# Ubuntu 19.10 fresh install, no mouse detected when plugged in thru KVM

Tags: mouse, kvm-virtualization

I just installed a larger NVMe drive into my Dell XPS 13 (9370). It previously had a SATA M.2 drive with just Linux Mint 19.2 on it. During the install process and after installing and applying updates my mouse is still not working with Ubuntu 19.10 when setup how it always used to work, but if I plug the mouse directly into my laptop dock it works.

For the record, this is my setup:

- A Dell XPS 13 9370
- A Dell WD15 Dock
- A ConnectPro UD-12+ KVM (for switching back and forth to my Windows gaming desktop)
- A Logitech G903 mouse with the Logitech G Powerplay Wireless charging mousepad

After installing the new SSD I installed Windows 10 (trying to get back to dual booting for a few 3D modeling tools), got to the desktop and rebooted immediately to start installing Ubuntu. The mouse wasn't working which was strange but I continued anyways. Once I was done with the install I rebooted into the Live CD one more time to shrink the partition (two 256GB partitions for Windows and Linux (minus whatever small partitions either wanted to make during install), one 500GB partition for a shared drive), then got into the actual install on the SSD. The mouse still wasn't working so I ran Software Updater, rebooted again, and still nothing. The laptop's touchpad is working fine. I flipped the KVM over to the gaming desktop, mouse works, rebooted the laptop into Windows, mouse works, went into the BIOS settings where the mouse also still works. So, not a problem with the mouse or not specifically an issue with the setup.

I reset the dock, unplugged and plugged the mouse back in, etc, etc, nothing. Plugged the mouse directly into the dock and it works. I tried Wayland from the login prompt, no change.

I do see in lsusb a Logitech, Inc. device listed (046d:c53a) and the mouse/mousepad should be the only device(s), however it doesn't get unlisted when I unplug the mouse from the KVM. When I plug the mouse directly into the dock I see another item, same device ID (046d:c53a), but listed as Logitech, Inc. USB2137B. So it looks like the KVM isn't able to fully pass the device to Ubuntu 19.10. I use that phrasing specifically because it worked in Linux Mint 19.2, Windows 10, the BIOS, and I booted a Linux Mint 19.2 live CD again and it works there still.

As this setup worked without major issues previously I'm thrown as to why it would stop working with Ubuntu 19.10. I'm guessing the kernel version change? Maybe something about Xorg? I'm just at a loss for what to try to get the mouse working with the KVM. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the same thing is happening on my machine. It's a desktop made out of various components, but connecting via KVM doesn't work, whereas plugging in mouse and keyboard directly works. Switched wires and inputs to rule out hardware being the issue, but this seems software related.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue while using a KVM switch. While installing Ubuntu, my mouse and keyboard were not being recognized. I had the dongle plugged into my KVM and the corresponding cable from the KVM connected to my 3.0 usb port. My mouse and keyboard were not working in this configuration. So, I tried switching the usb cord from the KVM to the PC over to a 2.0 usb port, and that did the trick. It seems to me there is an issue with ubuntu/kvm and 3.0 usb ports. Try moving to a 2.0 if you have one available and see if that works.